# Generate all IP addresses given a string in scala

Tags: scala, recursion

I was trying my hand at writing an IP generator given a string of numbers. The generator would take as an input a string of number such as "`17234`" and will return all possible list of ips as follows:

```
1.7.2.34
1.7.23.4
1.72.3.4
17.2.3.4
```

I attempted to write a snippet to do the generation as follows:

```
def genip(ip:String):Unit = {
    def legal(ip:String):Boolean = (ip.size == 1) || (ip.size == 2) || (ip.size == 3)
    def genips(ip:String,portion:Int,accum:String):Unit = portion match {
        case 1 if legal(ip) => println(accum+ip)
        case _ if portion > 1 => {
            genips(ip.drop(1),portion-1,if(accum.size == 0) ip.take(1)+"." else accum+ip.take(1)+".")
            genips(ip.drop(2),portion-1,if(accum.size == 0) ip.take(2)+"." else accum+ip.take(2)+".")
            genips(ip.drop(3),portion-1,if(accum.size == 0) ip.take(3)+"." else accum+ip.take(3)+".")
        }
        case _ => return
    }
    genips(ip,4,"")
}
```

The idea is to partition the string into four octets and then further partition the octet into strings of size `"1","2" and "3"` and then recursively descend into the remaining string.

I am not sure if I am on the right track but it would be great if somebody could suggest a more functional way of accomplishing the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is the right idea; I'm not sure making it functional really helps anything, but I'll show both functional and side-effecting ways to do what you want.  First, we'd like a good routine to chunk off some of the numbers, making sure an okay number are left for the rest of the chunking, and making sure they're in range for IPs:

```
def validSize(i: Int, len: Int, more: Int) = i + more <= len && i + 3*more >= len
def chunk(s: String, more: Int) = {
  val parts = for (i <- 1 to 3 if validSize(i, s.length, more)) yield s.splitAt(i)
  parts.filter(_._1.toInt < 256)
}
```

Now we need to use chunk recursively four times to generate the possibilities.  Here's a solution that is mutable internally and iterative:

```
def genIPs(digits: String) = {
  var parts = List(("", digits))
  for (i <- 1 to 4) {
    parts = parts.flatMap{ case (pre, post) =>
      chunk(post, 4-i).map{ case (x,y) => (pre+x+".", y) }
    }
  }
  parts.map(_._1.dropRight(1))
}
```

Here's one that recurses using `Iterator`:

```
def genIPs(digits: String) = Iterator.iterate(List((3,"",digits))){ _.flatMap{
  case(j, pre, post) => chunk(post, j).map{ case(x,y) => (j-1, pre+x+".", y) }
}}.dropWhile(_.head._1 >= 0).next.map(_._2.dropRight(1))
```

The logic is the same either way.  Here it is working:

```
scala> genIPs("1238516")
res2: List[String] = List(1.23.85.16, 1.238.5.16, 1.238.51.6,
                          12.3.85.16, 12.38.5.16, 12.38.51.6,
                          123.8.5.16, 123.8.51.6, 123.85.1.6)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative version of the attached code:

```
  def generateIPs(digits : String) : Seq[String] = generateIPs(digits, 4)

  private def generateIPs(digits : String, partsLeft : Int) : Seq[String] = {
    if ( digits.size < partsLeft || digits.size > partsLeft * 3) {
      Nil
    } else if(partsLeft == 1) {
      Seq(digits)
    } else {
      (1 to 3).map(n => generateIPs(digits.drop(n), partsLeft - 1)
        .map(digits.take(n) + "." + _)
      ).flatten
    }
  }

  println("Results:\n" + generateIPs("17234").mkString("\n"))
```

Major changes:

- Methods now return the collection of strings (rather than Unit), so they are proper functions (rather than working of side effects) and can be easily tested;
- Avoiding repeating the same code 3 times depending on the size of the bunch of numbers we take;
- Not passing accumulated interim result as a method parameter - in this case it doesn't have sense since you'll have at most 4 recursive calls and it's easier to read without it, though as you're loosing the tail recursion in many case it might be reasonable to leave it.

Note: The last `map` statement is a good candidate to be replaced by `for` comprehension, which many developers find easier to read and reason about, though I will leave it as an exercise :)